# How to Identify caller when grant_type is client_credentials?

Tags: identityserver3

I have ASP.NET Web application and I am using IdentityServer3 for user authentication. Our customers login to web application using userid/password.
Now I have one more Web API and some of our customers need to call this web api from their applications. (server to server communication). So based on [this](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/simplestOAuth.html), in identityserver  i did the following

1> Created a new scope name `api`
2> Created a new client for Web API and configured with allowed scope `api` and `offline_access`
3> Set flow to `ClientCredentials`
4> Set AccessTokenType to `Jwt`
5> **For each customer i created different secret key**

Now our customers can get access token at `connect/token` endpoint and then make call to API using the access token. The API validates the token with IdentityServer, and then returns the result. All good till here.

However, in API project i also need to identify the `customer` aka `caller`. Based on customer i need to do some logic

```
public class ResourcesController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {            
        var caller = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        // need to identify caller here
        return Json(new
        {
            message = "OK",
        });
    }
}
```

*(One option i can think of is taking customer id is as part of API url. Something like `http://api.domain.com/v1/customerid/resources`)*

Is there anyway to make a use of IdentityServer to identify customer?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had a similar need some time ago. For the simplest solution, you should be able to assign a custom claim to each of the Identity Server client that you have created for your customers.

```
AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,                     
Claims = new List<Claim>()
{
  new Claim("CustomerId", "0121021") 
}
```

These client claims will then be included in the access token and therefore available to you in your backend.

```
public class ResourcesController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {            
        var caller = User as ClaimsPrincipal;

        // need to identify caller here
        var customerId = caller?.Claims.Where(p => p.Type.Equals("CustomerId")).First().Value;
        // need to identify caller here

        return Json(new
        {
            message = "OK",
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The `client` in identityserver is actually an application, in this case my `api` is the client. So i have only one `client` in identityserver. I dont have multiple clients for each caller. and for `api` client then i added different `secret key` for each caller

Comment: @LP13 That’s not right then. You are misunderstanding OAuth and client credentials flow. Api is a resource and entity accessing that resource is a client. You need to have  a client per customer, not a secret for the same client per customer.